# Delphi, How can I pass a variable to a procedure from a MultiThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

```
procedure TForm4.WorkerThread(Thread: TMultiThreadThread;
  Parameters: TObject; var Data, Results: TObject);
var 
  clMailMessage1 : TclMailMessage;
  myVariable : string;
begin
  myVariable := 'A String from this Thread';
  clMailMessage1 := TclMailMessage.Create(self);
  clMailMessage1.OnSaveAttachment := clMailMessage1SaveAttachment;
  clMailMessage1.LoadMessage('myemail.eml'); 
  // The LoadMessage activates/calls the OnSaveAttachment procedure
  clMailMessage1.free;
end;

procedure TForm4.clMailMessage1SaveAttachment(Sender: TObject;
ABody: TclAttachmentBody; var AFileName: string; var AData: TStream;
var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  AData := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmCreate);
  // saves all attachments
  // **How do I access the myVariable here from the specific calling thread ?**
end;
```

I would like to access the myVariable from the clMailMessage1SaveAttachment procedure, but I can't figure out how.

Some code would be nice, because this is abit over my league I guess.

Answer (score 2):

`myVariable` is local to `WorkerThread()`, so `clMailMessage1SaveAttachment()` cannot see it.

If `TclMailMessage` offers a way to associate user-defined data then you can use that to pass around a pointer to `myVariable`, eg:

```
procedure TForm4.WorkerThread(Thread: TMultiThreadThread;
  Parameters: TObject; var Data, Results: TObject);
var 
  clMailMessage1 : TclMailMessage;
  myVariable : string;
begin
  myVariable := 'A String from this Thread';
  clMailMessage1 := TclMailMessage.Create(self);
  clMailMessage1.SomeUserDefinedData := @myVariable; // <-- here
  //...
end;

procedure TForm4.clMailMessage1SaveAttachment(Sender: TObject;
  ABody: TclAttachmentBody; var AFileName: string; var AData: TStream;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  myVariable: PString;
begin
  myVariable := PString(TclMailMessage(Sender).SomeUserDefinedData);
  // use myVariable^ as needed...
end;
```

For instance, if `TclMailMessage` is a `TComponent` descendant, you can use the public `Tag` property:

```
clMailMessage1.Tag := NativeInt(@myVariable);
...
myVariable := PString(TclMailMessage(Sender).Tag);
```

Otherwise, if defining user-defined data is not an option, you can move `myVariable` into global scope and mark it as [`threadvar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables#Thread-local_Variables) instead, eg:

```
threadvar
  myVariable : string;

procedure TForm4.WorkerThread(Thread: TMultiThreadThread;
  Parameters: TObject; var Data, Results: TObject);
var 
  clMailMessage1 : TclMailMessage;
begin
  myVariable := 'A String from this Thread';
  try
    clMailMessage1 := TclMailMessage.Create(self);
    clMailMessage1.OnSaveAttachment := clMailMessage1SaveAttachment;
    clMailMessage1.LoadMessage('myemail.eml'); 
    clMailMessage1.free;
  finally
    myVariable := ''; // important to free thread-specific memory
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.clMailMessage1SaveAttachment(Sender: TObject;
  ABody: TclAttachmentBody; var AFileName: string; var AData: TStream;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  // use myVariable as needed...
end;
```